# Get the default Directory for sounds

Tags: android, file, audio

my app use built in app : Voice recorder, that save me audio files in :

```
/storage/sdcard0/Sounds/
```

Is there a way to get this directory with a system variable, or should I hardcode it???

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is equal to this one, only this one will work on all devices since it's no guarantee that a specific device will mount it's storage into `sdcard0`

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "Sounds";
```

There is no default location for recordings, but there is one for music ([Enviroment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_MUSIC)) and
ringtones ([Enviroment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)) if you want to use any of them.

Comment: what if my cel has no SD card?

Comment: it returns the path to the internal

Comment: Is there a way to get "Sounds" directory programmatically?